# How to modify native-base datepicker's background?

Tags: react-native, datepicker, native-base, ios-darkmode

It seems in iOS dark mode there is a generic problem with date pickers (not specific to native-base).

In order to workaround that problem I want to set the background color of the modal. But I could not figure out if it even possible or not...

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { DatePicker } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { chosenDate: new Date() };

    this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
  }
  setDate(newDate) {
    this.setState({ chosenDate: newDate });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text />
        <Text />
        <Text />
        <DatePicker
          defaultDate={new Date(1976, 12, 23)}
          minimumDate={new Date(1940, 1, 1)}
          maximumDate={new Date(2040, 12, 31)}
          locale={'en'}
          timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
          modalTransparent={false}
          animationType={'fade'}
          androidMode={'default'}
          placeHolderText="Select date"
          textStyle={{ color: 'green' }}
          placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: '#d3d3d3' }}
          onDateChange={this.setDate}
        />
        <Text>Date: {this.state.chosenDate.toString().substr(4, 12)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

The code is as an Expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@mehmetkaplan/native-base-datepicker-test), and to experience the problem you can try with iOS dark mode and light mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by customizing your theme variables.

For reference see these links

https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/ThemeVariables.html

https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theme-and-variables-headref

Comment: The links are broken